# UK/Schengen visa

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

I am a British citizen living in South Africa and married to a South African citizen.

Does my wife need a visa to visit the UK with me (holiday)?
Does my wife need a Schengen visa to visit Europe with me (holiday)?

Comment: You can check whether a visa is required to enter the U.K. here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Answer (score 1):

> Does my wife need a visa to visit the UK with me (holiday)?

Yes.

> Does my wife need a Schengen visa to visit Europe with me (holiday)?

Yes, if by "Europe" you mean "the Schengen area," though as long as the UK remains in the EU free movement scheme, her visa should be free of charge and the application considered through an accelerated procedure.